# What's difference between number with $ or without $ symbol in at&t assembly syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, immediate-operand

Let's say .data section has following item:

```
0x1234 00010203 04050607 08090a0b 0c0d0e0f
0x1238 10000000
```

And in code,

```
mov $0x1234, %eax
mov 0x1238, %ebx
```

I believe with $ symbol, it would be constant number, so %eax will have memory address, but what about %ebx?

What exactly different between two instruction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that with `$` it's the **numeric value** while without `$` it's the contents of memory at that address

> If argument of instruction is without any special marker (such as % for register or $ for numeric constant), then it is memory access. So following:
>
> ```
> movl 10, %eax
> movl foo, %eax
> ```
>
> Corresponds to intel syntax:
>
> ```
> mov eax, [10]
> mov eax, [foo]
> ```
>
> To use numeric constant, or use address of label, there is $ operator:
>
> ```
> movl $10, %eax
> movl $foo, %eax
> ```
>
> In Intel syntax:
>
> ```
> mov eax, 10
> mov eax, offset foo
> ```
>
> http://x86asm.net/articles/what-i-dislike-about-gas/

Comment: So are you saying `mov $0x1238, %ebx` is just numeric constant and not memory access even though 0x1238 address is present in memory ?

Comment: `Memory access` here is data, not instruction