# in x86-64 assembly my eax register keeps resetting itself to 0 before the return

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to return the length of an int array and for some reason it sets to 0 after the loop and before the return

```
xor %eax, %eax
mov %rax, (%rdi)
loop_start:
  cmp $0, %rax
  je loop_end
  add %rax, 4
  inc %eax
  jmp loop_start
loop_end:

ret
```

this returns 0 instead of the number it should

I tried incrementing in different orders, I've tried adding another register to use with increment then set eax to it, both of those don't work and usually led to segfualts. I also tried an inc after the loop end and it returns 1 like it should, I've also set eax to different numbers after loop end and it returned whatever I entered as expected if I do that before the loop the code will seg fault

Comment: EAX is the low half of RAX.  This code adds `5` until EAX becomes zero, with `inc %eax` zero-extending the low 32 bits to fill RAX.  IDK what you wanted this code to do, but I'm guessing you didn't realize that was the same register?  Because as written, the only way out of the loop is for `je loop_end` to be taken, which only happens when the full RAX (and thus EAX) is zero.

Comment: I didn't know that part, rax is meant to be used for the array which is passed in as rdi the final element of those is 0 so I am trying to compare it to that for the loop_end condition. What should I do for that issue so they don't do that.

Comment: Also, I don't see how this would find the length of an array.  Is RDI supposed to be pointing to a `ssize_t` negative length in bytes, and you're incrementing it by 4 until zero?  Or maybe you were intending to look for the first zero element, if the array isn't allowed to have zeros other than a terminator?  But your loop doesn't load from memory.  Oh wait, yes it does, this is AT&T syntax so `add %rax, 4` adds RAX to the 8 bytes of memory at absolute address `4`.

Comment: And again being AT&T syntax, `mov %rax, (%rdi)` is an 8-byte store of RAX (which you just zeroed).  Perhaps you intended that to be `mov (%rdi), %rax` to load the first 8 bytes of the array into RAX?  That would be the first 2 elements of an `int` array.  Or `mov %rdi, %rax` to copy the pointer, and then `cmpl $0, (%rax)` to check 4 bytes of memory, an int element?  With code like this, hard to guess what you were trying to do since you didn't describe it in words.

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried using mov (%rdi), %rax and mov %rdi, %rax and both caused segfaults at loop start

Comment: Like I said, `add %rax, 4` access memory at absolute address `4`, so it'll always segfault if reached (if the loop doesn't exit before the first iteration).  Use a debugger to single-step and see register values change, and which insn faults.  [What's difference between number with $ or without $ symbol in at&t assembly syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18996870) .  So any change you made to fix the other code would expose that bug.